# JS how to get photo from api and using FileReader() add it to localStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, storage, filereader

I'm struggling for some time. I have an Api that gives me photo in image/jpeg. I want it to be saved in localStorage using FileReader(). anyone can help?

I tried using File() and all dumb solutions.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to fetch it and then convert it to a blob string; here is an example:

```
const API_URL = "https://source.unsplash.com/collection/928423/480x480";

function App() {
  const imageRef = React.useRef<HTMLImageElement>(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [isError, setIsError] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      const blobString = event.target?.result as string;
      localStorage.setItem("image", blobString);
      if (imageRef.current) imageRef.current.setAttribute("src", blobString);
    });

    fileReader.addEventListener("error", () => setIsError(true));

    fetch(API_URL)
      .then((res) => res.blob())
      .then((blob) => fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob))
      .catch(() => setIsError(true));
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const image = localStorage.getItem("image");
    if (image && imageRef.current) imageRef.current.setAttribute("src", image);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        {isLoading ? "Hold on!" : isError ? "Ops! There is an error!" : "Done!"}
      </h1>
      <img ref={imageRef} alt="test-imag3" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is the running code sandbox if you wanna test it:

https://codesandbox.io/s/store-image-in-localstorage-kj8606?file=/src/App.tsx

p.s: **consider using indexedDB instead of localStorage due to 5Mg storage limitation**